# Unable to locate any element using selenuim webscraper

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, aws-lambda

however i didn't change anything in the code. the website html code has changed suddenly and     look like this . so using selenuim i couldn't locate any element in the code. this is my source code :
noting that i'm used lambda service to run step function en parallel

[image]

that call this function with different indexes

```
def get_cpu_info(start_index, end_index):
    driver = get_driver()
    driver.get(url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    \# find the servers element
    \# Interact with the element
    cpu_attributes = \[\]
    for i in range(start_index, end_index):
    cpus_dict = {}
    name = ""
    codename = None
    tdp = None
    release_date = None
    try:
    name =  driver.find_element(By.XPATH,          f'//div\[@id="list"\]/table/tbody/tr\[{i}\]/td\[1\]').text
    except:
    pass
    if name not in "EPYC" or name not in "Xeon":
    continue
    
            try:
                    codename = driver.find_element(By.XPATH?f'//div[@id="list"]/table/tbody/tr[{i}]/td[2]').text
            except:
                pass
            try:
                tdp = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//div[@id="list"]/table/tbody/tr[{i}]/td[8]').text
            except:
                pass
            try:
                release_date = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//div[@id="list"]/table/tbody/tr[{i}]/td[9]').text
            except:
                pass
            if "EPYC" in name:
                cpus_dict['brand'] = "AMD"
            else:
                cpus_dict['brand'] = "Intel"
            cpus_dict['name'] = name
            cpus_dict['codename'] = codename
            cpus_dict['tdp'] = tdp
            cpus_dict['release_date'] = release_date
            # Interact with the element
            name_link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//div[@id="list"]/table/tbody/tr[{i}]/td[1]/a').get_attribute(
                'href')
            driver.get(name_link)
            time.sleep(5)
            frequency = None
            turbo_clock = None
            base_clock = None
            pcie = None
            number_of_cores = None
            number_of_threads = None
            try:
                frequency = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                                '//div[@class="sectioncontainer"]/section[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td').text
            except:
                pass
        
            try:`your text`
                turbo_clock = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                                  '//div[@class="sectioncontainer"]/section[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td').text
            except:
                pass
        
            try:
                base_clock = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                                 '//div[@class="sectioncontainer"]/section[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td').text
            except:
                pass
        
            try:
                pcie = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                           '//div[@class="sectioncontainer"]/section[3]/table/tbody/tr[10]/td').text
            except:
                pass`
        
            try:
                number_of_cores = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                                      '//div[@class="sectioncontainer"]/section[4]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td').text
            except:
                pass
        
            try:
                number_of_threads = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                                        '//div[@class="sectioncontainer"]/section[4]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td').text
            except:
                pass
        
            cpus_dict['frequency'] = frequency
            cpus_dict['turbo-clock'] = turbo_clock
            cpus_dict['base_clock'] = base_clock
            cpus_dict['pcie'] = pcie
            cpus_dict['number_of_cores'] = number_of_cores
            cpus_dict['number_of_threads'] = number_of_threads
            cpu_attributes.append(cpus_dict)
            driver.back()  # navigate back to CPU table page
        save_to_db(cpu_attributes)
        return cpu_attributes .
```

if some one could help me solving this problem!